# Expected Expression

Tags: javascript

I cannot figure out what I did or did not do here syntactically to cause this error.  I don't see what's missing:

```
function ShowWaitMessage(button)
{
    var isValid;

    if (buttonSelected())
    {
        showWaitMessage(button, "showMessage1");
        isValid = true;
    }
    else
    {
        Page_ClientValidate();
        if (Page_IsValid)
        {
            showWaitMessage(button, "showMessage2");
            isValid = true;
        }
    }

    return isValid;
}
```

Comment: I would look into the parts in the if statements more closely!

Comment: my fault.  I had a comment right on the same line as one of my if statements..you can't do that unfortunately and I hate that.  That was the problem that you would not have seen here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a comment on the same line as one of my if statements....causing this whole issue.

Comment: Well that's odd, is that correct Javascript behaviour?
Congrats anyway :)

Comment: yea, same for C#.  You cannot comment on the same line as your if or else, and so fourth.

Comment: Amazing! "Expected expression: ." and "Expected identifier: ." were driving me mad, appearing after a gulp bundle/minify just for two of the bundles, only on the first build & run after modifications (VS2019). Turns out one of the source files had a comment on the same line as an if statement and moving that solved it. I have no idea why it works after the first build when running the task manually but I hope this helps someone else who was going as mad as I was. NB file compare of the bundled & minified output from a "good" run with a "bad" run didn't show a single difference.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's anything syntactically wrong with your code, having "run" it in both FireFox and IE.  (By "run" I mean "loaded in a `<script>` tag", which ought to find syntax errors.)

What line does the error message point to?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a declaration of the Page_IsValid variable.  I'm guessing that it's a local variable set inside of Page_ClientValidate, which isn't in scope in this function?

You should probably also initialize isValid to false instead of leaving it undefined if both checks fail.